# Lines above and below the abstract

Tags: abstract

I need one line above the abstract and other line below the abstract. The width of lines should be equal to the width of abstract. The lines should not be larger than the width of the abstract and the abstract title must be centered.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{abstract,lipsum}
\usepackage[paperwidth=7.25in, paperheight=9.5in,bindingoffset=.75in] 
{geometry}
\begin{document}
\title{Contribution Title}
\author{Name of First Author and Name of Second Author}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}
Each chapter should be preceded by an abstract (10--15 lines long) that 
summarizes the content. The abstract will appear  and be available with 
unrestricted access. This allows unregistered users to read the abstract as 
a teaser for the complete chapter. As a general rule the abstracts will not 
appear in the printed version of your book unless it is the style of your 
particular book or that of the series to which your book belongs.
\rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}
\end{abstract}
\section{introduction}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you need this because your university demands that all theses have these lines?  Or is there some other reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest approach is to redefine the `abstract` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=7.25in,
  paperheight=9.5in,
  bindingoffset=.75in,
  heightrounded,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewenvironment{abstract}
 {\quotation\small\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}\par\smallskip
  {\centering\bfseries\abstractname\par}\medskip}
 {\par\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}\endquotation}

\begin{document}

\title{Contribution Title}
\author{Name of First Author and Name of Second Author}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Each chapter should be preceded by an abstract (10--15 lines long) that 
summarizes the content. The abstract will appear  and be available with 
unrestricted access. This allows unregistered users to read the abstract as 
a teaser for the complete chapter. As a general rule the abstracts will not 
appear in the printed version of your book unless it is the style of your 
particular book or that of the series to which your book belongs.
\end{abstract}

\section{introduction}
\lipsum*[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]