# How to Create a Good Design for my Abstract

Tags: abstract

I don't know how to create a good abstract design like the one on Elsarticle. I would like by Abstract to be bordered by lines and the Abstract title moved to the left.

Comment: first of all you need to describe more about your project, because it is unclear. Do you have an article template already and you want to modify the abstract design or are you making the new document/article with an abstract? I hope this answered question will help:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436603/lines-above-and-below-the-abstract?rq=1